# How to check if Content-Type is manipulated before hitting the server

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data

```
-----------------------------28762240629868
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: text/html

ÿØÿà
....
```

If someone has deliberately changed the Content-Type from image/jpeg to text/html, how to detect it in server side ?

Comment: i assume you are checking the mime type? I don't really think mime types are easily spoofed

Answer (score 0):

There could be a possibility that client can send files with manipulated content type. If you expect that the incoming attachment is going to be always image, then check for the height and width of image using below functions. If it return FALSE then its not an image.

```
imagesx($img);
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php

```
imagesy($img);
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

**Important:**

For the safety purpose, DO NOT render/execute the attachment from url on webpage if you are not sure. Just always force download image. Send headers and force downloading it so that just in case user is able to upload say .EXE file then still he will not able to execute on browser.

Comment: I'm already using getimagesize to verify it's image or not. Is there any way to get the Content-Type, ie; "text/html" ?

Comment: You can use `exif_imagetype()` php function to determine content-type. it reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature.